Name of the form load reference does not change in c#
When I change the form name from the solution explorer, the name of the form load reference does not change.
For example, while the name of the new form is form321, it still appears as form2.
 private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     form321 _form= new form321();
 }

How can I fix this?

Form2_Load is a name of a method which is probably auto-generated. it is given at the time the method is generated and does not change automatically when you change the class name. You can do it manually.

You can use the right-click menue to rename things in-depth.

There's nothing to fix. If you want to change the name of a method, change the name of the method. It's unrelated to the form's class name other than by convention. In future, change the name of your form when you create it, so no event handlers are created with the wrong name.

@TaW, I assume that you are referring to the ability to change all references to a the class to match the new name. That would have no effect here. It's not going to change method names.

Picking a good Form class name early is recommended.  To rename the method in a safe way, be sure to right-click the method name and choose Rename.  That refactors the event handler name both in the design-time code and your own code.

I think there's maybe not enough detail here, but changing the file name, does not change the name of the class that is instantiating Form2.  Look for something like
public class Form2 

in your code base.  It's probably in a partial class that represents the object instantiation for Form2.  Change that, and then the name will be different.

The OP is asking how to automatically change the name of a method that contains the form's name, which obviously is not a thing.

Ahh, I get ya.  He said he changed it in solution explorer...which threw me off. Actually...I just re-read it again, and I'm guessing he's copying and pasting an existing form as a new one, into the solution..."the name of the new form" - and he wants to change the generated name of it.
